# Unable to show/hide a component in a map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have an array of items which contain text, value pairs. I need to display text only if it is not null and value is never null and I display it normally.

```js
var items= [ 
  {id: 1, title: "title1", property: {text: null, value: 222}}, 
  {id: 2, title: "title2", property : {text: "star", value: 123}}, 
  {id: 3, title: "title3", property:{text: "sun", value: 456}}, 
  {id: 4, title: "title4", property: {text: null, value: 789}}
];
```

For this what I did is :

```js
class DisplayItems extends Component {
  render() {
    return ({
      items.map(item => {
        return (
          showIf(!isEmpty(item.property.text))(
            <Text>
              text: {item.property.text}
            <Text />
          ),(
            <Text>
            value: {item.property.value}
            <Text />
          )
        )
      })
    })
  }
}
```

But the thing is even when the item.property.text is null it is entering into the showIf condition and also text is not getting rendered if it has some string in it. showIf is an internal function which hides the components if the condition is false. Please help with this issue as I want to render one property (text) but display other property (value) irrespective of the condition.

Comment: You need `&&` operator

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the second return statement. If you look closely, that is not the valid jsx. You should change it to this:

```
class DisplayItems extends Component {

render() {
    return (

            { 
              items.map(item => {
                   return (
                            <Text>
                                 { showIf(!isEmpty(item.property.text))? "text: " + item.property.text : "text: " + item.property.value}
                            <Text/>
                         )
              })
            }
    )
}
```

}

Comment: I want to render the item.property.value irrespective of the condition succeeds or fails

Comment: The problem is because you are mixing text and expression in the tag <Text>. I have updated the solution. Hope that will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could solve it for you:

```
class DisplayItems extends Component {

render() {
    return (
            { 
              items.map(item => {
                    return (
                          <Text>
                              { item.property.text && `text: ${item.property.text}` }
                              value: {item.property.value}
                          <Text/>
                      )
                });
            }
        )
    }
}
```